# Optimize zend framework + Doctrine2 web application

Tags: zend-framework, optimization, frameworks, doctrine-orm

We had an big application written in PHP+js+mysql. some of our bosses, decided (making a big mistake since they are no developers) to give this application in outsourcing for rewritting it from a developer company. They rewritte the application with Zend Framework+ Doctrine, giving us back a very veru very slow application, if in the old application on module to load taked 1 second now it takes 4 seconds.

Till now we have done the impossible to fast up this up: activated cache server, migrate application to linux, caching everything possible but it is still very slow very slow.

**I need from all developers experience how to optimize and make faster this application written with zend framework and doctrin2 (we cannot remove doctrine, and we have alreedy implemented the cache system)? tips tricks, ideas any anwser will be welcome.**

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to go through the code and see what they did.  If you have APC enabled, there's no reason ZendFramework and Doctrine should be taking 4 seconds to load (unless there's a poorly written database query).  There's all kinds of things they could have done incorrectly.

Comment: we got some speed up when we move the web application from windows server to linux centos server, we have seen some of queries with getSql and getDql command of doctrine and there are some mostrouses queries with a lot of joins and alias, but really we do know if some of this queries are generated automatically from doctrine

Comment: You're going to want to enable the slow query log as suggested in one of the answers then.  And profile those queries to see how much time they're taking.

Answer (score 1):

Same as with any PHP application:

- Enable Xdebug on your development machine and do some profiling to see where the bottlenecks are
- Enable the MySQL slow query log to see if the queries can be improved

you can also look at the DB profiling features in `Zend_Db` to see if the app is doing unnecessary queries or loading more data than it needs.

Answer (score 1):

For all website application use this firebug's pluggins for optimize your code, you can really win in performance !

[Yahoo Yslow pluggin](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

[Google PageSpeed pluggin](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)

with there, you have a notation for your page, with listing for improve your fastest's application.

After, for Doctrine2 , you can use fetchArray() for few little request, (global, users use fetchAll() ) .
FetchArray is more faster than fetchAll for request, just because fetchArray return just an Array, and fetchAll return all object linked in your request... ( many time, array is sufficient).

Hope I help You.

Comment: We already have done statistic and with firebug and Yslow, cached, optimize query doctrine dql when we could but the application results still slow

Comment: Okay, You have compared time request in Doctrine and Mysql ? there a different? or times are similar? and when you show your page without mysql(or dql)  treatment? display page is more faster? or is it slow too?

Comment: +1 for the fetchArray, but fetchAll command is used a little in the doctrine, we notice that for fechting the getResult command is used, that as you said returns all linked object. (doing a var_dump of a getResult gives a moustrous output.) Consider we have mediumly 170 tables in our database, and we have a database of this type for each client

Comment: Also, I forget a details :) when you using Doctrine with SYMFONY frameworks, preriquired is to use a PHP accelerator ([APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) ), maybe if you add an accelerator in your php project your dql request are faster...